# How to disable mod_security2 rule (false positive) for one domain on centos 5

Tags: apache-2.2, web, mod-security

Hi I have mod_security enabled on a centos5 server and one of the rules is keeping a user from posting some text on a form.  The text is legitimate but it has the words 'create' and an html `<table>` tag later in it so it is causing a false positive.

The error I am receiving is below:

`[Sun Apr 25 20:36:53 2010] [error] [client 76.171.171.xxx] 
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 500 (phase 2). Pattern match "((alter|create|drop)[[:space:]]+(column|database|procedure|table)|delete[[:space:]]+from|update.+set.+=)" at ARGS:body. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "352"] [id "300015"] [rev "1"] [msg "Generic SQL injection protection"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "www.mysite.com"] [uri "/node/181/edit"] [unique_id "@TaVDEWnlusAABQv9@oAAAAD"]`

and here is /usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf (line 352)

`#Generic SQL sigs
SecRule ARGS "((alter|create|drop)[[:space:]]+(column|database|procedure|table)|delete[[:space:]]+from|update.+set.+=)" "id:1,rev:1,severity:2,msg:'Generic SQL injection protection'"`

The questions I have are:

1. What should I do to "whitelist" or allow this rule to get through?
2. What file do I create and where?
3. How should I alter this rule?
4. Can I set it to only be allowed for the one domain, since it is the only one having the issue on this dedicated server or is there a better way to exclude table tags perhaps?

Thanks guys

Comment: nobody has any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the ModSecurity on a specific URL with LocationMatch directive, something like this:

```
<LocationMatch "/node/181/edit">
  <IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleEngine Off 
  </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Mod_security